Could a Project like Orion be built today with non nuclear weapons?
According to,
Project Orion

The optimal Orion drive bomblet yield (for the human crewed 4,000 ton
reference design) was calculated to be in the region of 0.15 kt, with
approx 800 bombs needed to orbit and a bomb rate of approx 1 per
second

And according to this,
Father of All Bombs

The bomb weighs around 7,100 kg and reportedly has an explosive yield
equivalent to 44 tons of TNT.

This is 29% of the yield of the nuclear bombs that Orion would need to work in theory. Storing this would add 5600 tons to the rocket, when the Falcon Heavy for example weights 1400 tons. The largest rocket ever to be built by SpaceX is said to weight 5000 tons Starship
Largest bombs could be created I suppose, to reach the theorized 0.15 kt of the Orion Project, but they would add more weight to the rocket (the accidental non nuclear explosion of Beirut for example, was calculated to have a yield of 0.5 - 1.1 kt)
Could a Project like Orion be built today with non nuclear weapons, or are there technical limitations like the weight of the bombs needed to be stored, or the way they need to be detonated?

There's a Jerry Pournelle science fiction novel "King David's Spaceship" where a non-nuclear Orion type ship is built and successfully makes it to orbit. But it's super minmal - no cabin, no re-entry system. Pournelle was usually good about the physics in his books, but I don't remember if he "cheated" by making the planet have lower gravity or something.

Consider the numbers you've quoted... a nuke is getting approximately 6 tonnes of explosive force per tonne of bomb, whereas conventional explosives are getting approximately 1 tonne per tonne (because that's what tonnage of explosive means). So your non-nuclear option is very short of power compared to the Orion.

Note that the FOAB is a fuel-air bomb, it can't work in space...

@OrganicMarble Pournelle didn't normally play "fast and loose" with physics, or if he did he admitted it. However if we move slightly further into speculative SF: I remember a story where somebody invented a protective forcefield, which was later abused to increase the strength of a bomb's tamper allowing criticality to be reached with microscopic amounts of fissile material. Hence if we could find some way (magic or otherwise) to drastically improve the strength-to-mass ratio of the material used to construct the casing of bombs...

You should add the bomb vital statistics for the 4000 ton reference design: from Wikipedia: 0.37-0.75 ton mass per bomb, 140 ton yield, ratio of about 300 x. The Fuel Air Bomb is only 5x (and it only works in dense air, and it's slow burning...)

Is the math a bit off here?  You need 800 bombs at 0.15kt per bomb.  But (ignoring other caveats) you're swapping in something that has only 29% of that yield.  Have to (roughly) triple the number of bombs to compensate.  So call it 2400 bombs at 7.1 tons per bomb, and that's 17,000 tons.  Quite a bit more than the 5600 tons stated in the question.

Yes, but it would be more efficient if you increased the number of non-nuclear bombs while reducing their size, and the best way to do this is to make the explosives liquid, make the explosion more gradual, at the rate the liquid can be pumped to the location of the "explosions". And it's even more efficient if the explosions don't even happen successively but continuously. Then instead of pusher plates, make that continuous explosion contained and direct it through a nozzle, so that less of the energy is dissipated in the wrong direction. Actually, all current spaceships use this method.

You could, but it's missing the point of the Orion system, and the new Orion will not reach ridiculous speeds.
Conventional explosives are using chemical energy, typically to create an expanding cloud of gas with associated shockwave. We already know, in rocket science, that you don't want to capture that with a pusher plate. You want to direct the gas stream out of an expanding nozzle (it should already be supersonic) to direct its momentum and better propel the spacecraft.  I believe, but don't have the resources handy to show convincingly right now, that you'll also end up with a lower specific impulse than a conventional hydrolox rocket because of the comparatively high molar mass of the propellant (even an azide is going to be carbon and nitrogen).
The point of a nuclear Orion is to harness the fantastically high energy and power density of a nuclear explosive (in order to reach ridiculous speeds, as you point out in your comment). It's built unusually in order to do that.
(An additional qualifier to the "you could" above: it's trivially believable that an explosion will push a plate, even in a vacuum. I do think that, owing to the radical efficiency changes above, you might have difficulty finding a mission profile that a non-nuclear-Orion could complete. It's definitely a niche vehicle, probably on the order of "an ancient civilization left this dreadfully irradiated plate attached to a spaceship in orbit here; we could use it as a spaceship with a bunch of regular bombs and that's slightly more convenient/novel/likely-to-get-Youtube-views at this point than cutting off the pusher plate system and figuring out a different propulsion system.")

I thought the purpose of Orion project was to reach ridiculous speeds, they believed they could reach 3% the speed of light

@Pablo yes, because of the tremendous energy density of nuclear weapons. Setting off a series of explosions behind your space ship is clearly a bad way to power your space ship. But it also the only way if you want to use nuclear weapons

@Pablo Yes, but that would only be possible because of the specific energy involved. Conventional explosives, discounting thermobaric systems, cap out around 10-20 MJ/kg in terms of specific energy (though most are at best half of that). By comparison, even the M29 Davey-Crockett (the smallest nuclear weapon system ever built) had a specific energy in the warhead of roughly 3.65 GJ/kg (in a roughly 50 kg warhead), two orders of magnitude higher, and the smallest Orion designs were looking at roughly 7.17 GJ energy yields per bomb (with what appear to be roughly 200 kg warheads).

@AustinHemmelgarn thank you for that comment; I was just about to write something similar to ensure that OP saw that the conventional Orion is not capable of reaching the high speeds that nuclear Orion can, even if it is capable of propelling itself conventionally.

@Pablo The basic Orion project vehicles that were well studied were not able to reach relativistic speeds - Orion was more notable for its combination of highish Isp and extreme thrust to weight ratio. Orion starships, really using fusion bombs rather than fission, were studied but these are not the familiar Orion vehicle.


This picture from xkcd sums it up quite neatly. Nuclear energy content is ridiculously more than oil or other chemical fuels. It should additionally be noted that explosives tend not to pack a lot of energy per mass unit, compared to other fuels.
Even if nuclear weapons are very inefficient, only converting tiny fractions of their mass into energy, the energy released per kilogram is far above what chemical explosives can do. A W54 nuclear warhead weighs in at under 25kg, and releases energy comparable to 20 tons of TNT.

As an addendum to Erin Anne's answer, during the testing phase for project Orion they did successfully fly a conventional explosive test vehicle (video), which demonstrates both that it is possible, and that the resulting performance is not particularly exciting compared to a similar sized rocket.
Along with the efficiency issues with using an Orion drive with conventional explosives, the videos make clear a thrust limit - thrust is only happening during each fireball, with a lengthy dead period between bursts as a new charge is ejected and positioned. Obviously this can be solved by emitting smaller charges more often, which taken to logical conclusion sounds like an ordinary rocket...
It is also worth noting that while a nuclear Project Orion is described as build-able with current technology, this does not mean all the engineering problems have been solved. In particular the mechanisms to safely store, position, arm and eject all the nuclear charges is generally glossed over as just a mechanical problem. In practice suspect that developing the mechanical parts of that process will involve at least as many fireballs and wrecked equipment as the current SpaceX Starship efforts.

"at least as many fireballs " and bigger ones!

What a lovely source!  Something else I suspect would be a problem:  your thrust is coming from repetitive explosive shock loads instead of "steadier" continuous burning. I'd expect that to require stronger structures than a rocket nozzle for equivalent average acceleration.

@ErinAnne in the Pournelle novel the vibration almost killed the crew.

@ErinAnne, building an appropriate shock absorber was seen as the major engineering challenge of building an Orion spacecraft.

@OrganicMarble actually the fireballs likely wouldn't be very big, albeit certainly very dirty. A nuclear bomb doesn't do its proper criticality thing unless the primers are set off with exactly the right timing, which wouldn't happen in an accident caused by problems in the ejector mechanism.

@leftaroundabout those bombs are still a quite substantial amount of conventional explosive (3 tonnes in Fat Man), so if you have a mechanical malfunction and a hundred or so devices in the feeder mechanism get busted up you are not getting your test rig back, even if you left out the nuclear cores. And you need to test with live explosives since they are the bits vulnerable to mechanical issues and shock. Even testing with fully inert devices is probably dicey - it needs to fire <hundred kg payloads every couple of seconds and that sounds like a serious artillery piece.

@GremlinWranger Fat Man is hardly representative, Orion propulsion would use as small bombs as feasible - rather something similar to a W54 warhead, which contains only 12 kg of explosives. Sure, you still wouldn't want those going off in your backback, but it's nowhere near the amount of destructive potential that a conventional rocket has.

Creating an answer from a comment on the question, because I think it answers the question most directly:
The ATBIP gets its impressive yield/weight ratio only because it is a fuel-air bomb; it doesn't include its own oxidizer as conventional explosives do, rather relying on atmospheric oxygen to react with the fuel in the bomb. This seems to give it a yield/weight ratio that might just work with an Orion setup, but has several implications ruling out its use in an Orion-type spacecraft: 1) The bombs won't work at high altitude; 2) The explosion is much slower; 3) the explosion is spread out over a considerable area.  2) and 3) would prevent it from working effectively against an Orion-type pusher plate.

Well, we could build a nozzle that collects loose oxygen atoms and compresses them into some kind of dense stream then set the explosive off there...  (This is a joke: I'm describing a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scramjet )

Orion used nuclear warheads not (just) because of the obsession with everything nuclear at the time, but mainly because of the energy density of nuclear warheads. The very high detonation speed compared to conventional explosives is important as well (and related).
Conventional explosives have relatively low energy density, and often slow detonation speeds. The MOAB you mention is a prime example, it is very slow and extremely heavy and bulky. For the same mass and size you can have a nuclear warhead in the hundreds of kilotons range.
The warheads planned for Orion would have been about the size of a 155mm artillery shell (and nuclear artillery shells this size were in fact fielded, with yields in the hundreds of tons range, compared to a yield of less than 1 ton for a 155mm conventional shell).
